# executable files and django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use executable files with Django. For instance I have a Django form that takes input a file. I want to pass the file as an argument to a script/executable/program and output the results back with django. What would be a good starting point for this idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: What does "executable" mean here?  Binary?  Script?  What -- **exactly** -- do you mean?  Further, how will you prevent the endless security problems this represents?

Comment: By executable I mean an application like the following example: I take an image/file as input pass the image/file as an argument to the application and modify the image.

Comment: So "executable files with Django" means some Python script or code that does some work?  Any Python script or code can be used with the Python that's part of Django.  What **exactly** confuses you about writing Python code for this?

Comment: I don't really understand how to use subprocess and pass the arguments to my executable. Also how do I specify the path of the executable.

Comment: "don't really understand how to use subprocess and pass the arguments to my executable".  Then **update** your question to actually say what your actual question actually is.

Answer (score 5):

[`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 1):

The question you should you be asking is it possible in python. Essentially all you would need to do it take in the inputs, into a python script which you can call from your django view or what not. Once there run the execute [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) command with your executable, and take in the results. :)

Goodluck.

Comment: "is it possible in python".  True -- the question is about Python the language, not Django the framework.  However, it is a *useless* question to ask.  Anything's possible in Python -- the question is how much work, how much risk and how many security holes.

Answer (score 1):

do you want some things like this?

```
>>> import commands 
>>> commands.getstatusoutput('pwd')
(0, '/home/efazati')
```

Comment: yes something like this but not with a standard unix command like pwd but with a custom script like ./myscript

Comment: @Bigdinrock its terminal ... you can use all thing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. There are a few different ways to do it in Python. If you want to read the output and use it then you probably want popen, found at http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen

Warning, this can be very dangerous. If the data added to the command line is malicious (even accidentally) then you could cause bad stuff to happen on the server. You're effectively giving people who submit forms the ability to run commands on the server with the same permissions the web server has.

```
import os
ls_fd = os.popen('ls -l /tmp')
output = ls_fd.read()
ls_fd.close()
```

Doing it this way your ls_fd is a file like object. you .read() it like a file. You can only do it once, then you're at the end of the file. Likewise, you should .close() it when you're done.

Strongly consider against adding user input to the command line. You can create a list of possible options and then give the user a choice which one they want. Then instead of taking the user's input and adding it to the end of the command line you can use one of your pre-configured command lines and execute that.

Comment: I do not want to use the input for the command line. I want to pass it as an argument to an application.

Comment: if you add it as an argment then it's still part of the command line and should be treated with care. For example: cmd = 'ls -l %s' % arg